# Linq Union Operator

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method:

```
public IList<Book> Search(IList<int> genre)
{    
    IQueryable<Book> books = database.Books;
    if (genres.Count > 0)
    {
        books = books.Include("Genres");
        foreach (int genreId in genres)
        {
            books = books.Union(books.Where(b => b.Genres.Any(g => g.Id == genreId)));
        }
    }
    return books.ToList()
}
```

It stops to work on the last line. Why? Maybe someone knows more efficient way to get all entities which belong corresponding genre id?

Comment: What do you mean by stops to work? The query is resolved at that point so if the query takes too long it will stay there until results are ready. For a better way of doing that look into `.Contains`

Comment: If you mean the next lines won't run when debugging, put a `try catch` between it and get the exception message to see the error

Comment: what error is it showing?

Comment: I'd note that `books.Union(books.Where(anyLambda))` is at best going to be the same as `books.Distinct()` because aside from the inherent `Distinct()` in any `Union` it is adding on those elements of `books` that match a criteria and aren't already in `books`. Since obviously all elements in `books` are already in `books` that does nothing.

Comment: This seems like it's a convoluted way to attempt `public IQueryable<Book> Search(IEnumerable<int> genre) { return books.Include("Genres").Where(b => b.Genres.Any(g => genre.Contains(g.Id)); } with perhaps the `Include("Genres")` not being needed.

Comment: @JonHanna: Almost. The `if` still needs to be there since, if no genres are specified, the full list of books is to be returned. (I'm assuming this is a case where `genres` is an optional filter than can be omitted.)

Comment: Is there a navigational property from `Genre` to `Book`? Can you say `genre1.Books`?

Comment: Is `genre` really a `IList<id>` or should that be `IList<int>`?

Comment: @juharr, you're right that should be IList<int>. Already fixed.

Comment: @YacoubMassad yep. In any case unioning something with a subset of itself as this is attempting is only going to be a null operation (aside from the inherent Distinct) if it did work.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should do it the other way around. I.e., go from genre to books like this:

```
return
    database
    .Genres
    .Where(g => genre.Contains(g.Id))
    .SelectMany(g => g.Books)
    .ToList();
```

This code assumes that there is a navigational property that goes from `Genre` to `Book` like this:

```
public class Genre
{
    public Genre()
    {
        Books = new HashSet<Book>();
        //...
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get;set;}
    //... Other properties here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test
{

    private List<Book> books = new List<Book>()
    {
        new Book
        {
            Id = 1,
            Genres = new List<Genre>()
            {
                new Genre
                {
                    Id = 1
                },
                new Genre
                {
                    Id = 2
                }
            }
        },
        new Book
        {
            Id = 2,
            Genres = new List<Genre>()
            {
                new Genre
                {
                    Id = 3
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public IList<Book> Search(IList<int> genres)
    {

        return books.Where(x => x.Genres.Any(y => genres.Contains(y.Id))).ToList();

    }

}
```

Made a quick example. In function Search only replace books with database.Books.

Test verifying the results.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

    Test t;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        t = new Test();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestGetBooksByGenre()
    {
        var result = t.Search(new List<int>()
        {
            1
        });

        Assert.IsTrue(result.Count == 1);
        Assert.IsTrue(result[0].Id == 1);
    }
}
```